# Delete lines based on patterns in another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files:

`input.txt`:

```
Hi 1-12T2EDD
1-13D62L6Hello
1-15SDWAKWazzup
Wow1-18Z3QWY
```

`filter.txt`:

```
1-15SDWAK
1-1VF3XHV
```

I want to delete lines with matching pattern from `filter.txt` in `input.txt`. In SQL understanding, I want to do left outer join `input.txt` with `filter.txt`.

`output.txt`:

```
Hi1-12T2EDD
1-13D62L6Hello
Wow1-18Z3QWY
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `grep` will do this:

```
$ grep -Fvf filter input
Hi 1-12T2EDD
1-13D62L6Hello
Wow1-18Z3QWY
```

Options:

- `-F` for fixed strings as we don't need regexp matching
- `-v` for inverse matching
- `-f` for specifing the file containing the strings to *(inverse)* match.