# delete lines with specific pattern

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Hi I have to delete some lines in a file:

```
file 1
1 2 3
4 5 6

file 2
1 2 3 6
5 7 8 7
4 5 6 9
```

I have to delete all the lines of file 1 that i find in file 2:

```
output
5 7 8 7
```

I used sed:

```
for sample_index in $(seq 1 3)
do
  sample=$(awk 'NR=='$sample_index'' file1)
  sed "/${sample}/d" file2 > tmp
done
```

but it doesnt work.it doesn't print anything. do you have any idea?It gives me error of 'sed: -e expression #1, char 0: precedent regular expression needed'

Comment: From your example you want to find a substring, not the whole line.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477782/delete-lines-based-on-pattern-on-another-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if your real data as 3 columns:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2$3]++;next}!($1$2$3 in a)' file{1,2}
```

For variable columns:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}{for(x in a) if(index($0,x)>0) next}1' file{1,2}
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be a start:

```
$ grep -vf file1 file2
5 7 8 7
```

One potential pitfall here is that the output won't change if you put `5 6 9` as the second line of `file1`. I'm not sure if if you want that or not. If not, you can try

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/' file1) file2
```

Comment: I can not use grep since i have negative numbers as well and he doesn't distinguish between positive ones. I would prefer to use awk but i dont know how

Comment: @user18350 Can you update your question with such an example? I'm not sure I understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

And the code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -r 's#(.*)#/\1/d#' file1 | sed -f - file2
```