# Delete lines based on another file

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a unix question similar to one that is being asked here

[Delete lines based on pattern on another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477782/delete-lines-based-on-pattern-on-another-file)

I have file1.txt whose contents are

```
part1
part2
part3
part4
```

I have another file2.txt whose content are (it has 2000 lines)

```
part1
part2
part3
...
part2000
```

I would like to remove all lines from file2.txt that match contents of file1.txt. I tried the solution in as suggested in the above post but those tags are not available for me on my SUN Unix server.

```
% grep -Fvf file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
grep: illegal option -- F
grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

Comment: "Delete lines based on another file" - sounds like a task for the `diff` utility, nisi fallor.

Comment: `cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq` ?

Comment: sort -u  if available but sort will display line from both file once, not remove line in file 2 with the one comming from file 1 like the question is ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on an older Solaris server, use the tools in `/usr/xpg4/bin` whenever possible.

```
$ /usr/bin/grep
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/grep 
Usage:  grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [file ...]
grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern... [-f pattern_file]...[file...]
grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern]... -f pattern_file [file...]
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. THat definitely did help. Though is there any faster way of doing this search and replace? In honesty I have 30,000 records in my flie1.txt and 300,000 in file2.txt and it is taking forever to this replace

Comment: given your sample data, `-x` would be appropriate

Comment: like this? grep -Fxf file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt. It doesn't do anything when I run it like that.

Comment: For large files like mine, this method does take some time but is the only solution that works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works

```
grep -v "`cat file1.txt`" file2.txt > tmp.in
```

Comment: maybe a fgrep to avoid regex issue

Comment: I get this error when I try this command % grep -v "`cat file1.txt`" file2.txt > tmp.in
Too many words from ``

Comment: In file1 I has 30,000 lines and file2 has 300,000 lines.