# Comparing and extracting data from two similar files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem: In file A and B I have a list of names and dates of birth the format is Joe Bloggs 01/01/1901.

File A has all the correct dates of birth. I have been trying to write code in Python that can run through file B and compare the name and date of birth and if it finds a duplicate to delete it, leaving behind all the incorrect entries.

This code creates a file with all the names and DOB that are incorrect which I can work with but I want to do exactly the same but with the correct DOB. Any ideas?

```
def build_set(filename):
    found = set()    

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            found.add(tuple(sorted(line.split()[:3])))

    return found

set_more = build_set('Incorrect.txt')
set_del = build_set('Correct.txt')

with open('results.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for res in (set_more - set_del):  
        out_file.write(" ".join(res) + "\n")
```

Comment: I repaired your posted code as best I could; please verify it is still what you actually wrote.

Comment: Isn't `set_del` all the correct DOBs?

Comment: If you just want to fix the files and don't need to do it in Python, you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477782/delete-lines-based-on-pattern-on-another-file useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new fie to only contain correct DOB why not take set difference once more?

```
with open('results.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for res in (set_del - (set_more - set_del)):  
        out_file.write(" ".join(res) + "\n")
```

Or is it something else that you are looking for?