# How can I remove lines containing a specific pattern and have a "pattern file"?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, the pattern file contains:

```
thepiratebay.org
some-url.com
```

Basically, lines with these patterns need to be removed from a file. How can I do that? I prefer a method that uses core utils.

Comment: `grep -vf pattern_file file` works well when the pattern list is small.  For large lists, this post has a better solution: [grep -vf too slow with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702425/grep-vf-too-slow-with-large-files).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete lines based on pattern in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477782/delete-lines-based-on-pattern-on-another-file)

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -vf pattern-file data-file  > new-file
mv new-file data-file
```

The `-v` gives lines which do not contain the pattern(s)

The `-f` specifies a file which contains the pattern(s)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be used for this operation as well.

```
 sed -i '/thepiratebay.org/d;/some-url.com/d' inputfile.txt
```

`d` option deletes the line after finding `/pattern/`. Use, `-i.bak` for `FreeBSD/MacOS`.

`-i` option edits file in-place and overwrites it in one go. `-i.bak` does the same, but copies the original file to `inputfile.txt.bak`.